# Android - Fragment History

Tags: android

I have this method to add a fragment :

```
public void addFragmentOnTop(Fragment fragment) {
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content, fragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
}
```

Assume that I will search item with key "earphone" in Home. Then the `R.id.content` will replace with SearchFragment. When I search again (not tap the back button to back to home, cause the SearchView is in toolbar) with key "headset", the `R.id.content` will replace again. The problem is, Why this generate a history fragment? When I tap back button, the `R.id.content` will show the search result with key "earphone". I have try with `getSupportFragmentManager().remove(SearchFragment.TAG);` but no affect to my apps. Anyone can help me? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.addToBackStack(null);`. It adds your `Fragment` on a backstack (creates that *Fragment history* that you are talking about), which is being poped by your `Activity` as soon as you press back button.

---

Hope this helps. Good luck :)